# What are the dangers of a leaking intermediate OAuth auth code?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

Say a user wants to authorize mykittenblog.com to make calls on his behalf to payment.com.
mykittenblog.com has people login at payment.com like so

```
payment.com/oauth2/authorize?id=12345&redirect=http://mykittenblog.com
```

So payment.com can respond with an intermediate auth code that mykittenblog.com can use together with its client secret to retrieve an OAuth  bearer token at payment.com

Now the 'redirect' parameter has an open redirect vulnerability that allows leaking of the auth code.

if a user logs in at

```
payment.com/oauth2/authorize?id=12345&redirect=http://evilserver.com/codestealer
```

payment.com will respond with

```
Location: http://evilserver.com/codestealer?code=4312871236481723874
```

What are the possible dangers in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intermediate authorization code is stolen by a malicious application, then it will be able to issue access tokens and get access to the resources. If a refresh token is also issued, then it will be able to renew that access token whenever it wants.

If your client is confidential, then the leak is limited (but not impossible) as the malicious client has to get your application credentials.

They are counter-measures to prevent that leak of code.
The registration of the redirect uris is a good start, but not sufficient.
Another way is the use of a Proof Key for Code Exchange described in the [RFC7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636). Without this PKCE, it is not possible for a malicious application to issue an access token as the challenge cannot be easily guessed.

From my point of view, the use of that the PKCE should always be done and not limited to the public clients.